# Is it possible to trace a specific datum in the program?

Tags: debugging, testing

Almost all tools of languages I used for debugging supports breakpoints and stepping mode, so I can watch a specific datum in the scope at a time. But I still feel pain when I missed the datum in some mystery paths of components in the program, especially when the it vaporized in some components with multiple entries and exits.

The pain may be killed if there is a tool can "tag" a datum and follow it, to report what functions ( or other basic computing unit ) had swallowed and transformed it. This should be like some medical test which feeds patients a radiative pill, and the doctor can trace it outside. I know the backtrace is almost I need, but it still a painful way to trace a datum between each frame.

According to my ( poor ) programming experience, the nearest tool/language is the Arrow mechanism in Haskell, which uses type system and composition to represent whole picture of the program's IPO paths. But it requires your program following the way it advocated, and I don't know whether it is the best way to implement the idea. Especially you can't easily program like that in other languages, like C, C++, Ruby, Java and JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite a tricky task. You could try to use Aspect-oriented Programming (AOP), to achieve this, but finding *all* accesses to a particular object (at least in Java) and instrumenting them is virtually impossible, I'd say.

The closest you can get is probably the so-called [`dflow`-pointcut in AOP](http://www.springerlink.com/content/0xrycbx8edpd5d6x/?MUD=MP), which alas hasn't been implemented anywhere as far as I know.

Your best bet will be setting up a debugger breakpoint with a trigger on a particular address-range where your datum lives (which you'd need to figure out first).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. AOP seems an acceptable way to trace some import data.